# extract values based on first 4 integers

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose, I have this dataframe (integers).

```rb
df <- data.frame(date = c(20010101:20010103, 20050304, 20050506, 20220113, 20220216))
```

And I have the target date like this:

```rb
target_date = 2001
```

I want to extract only those values from `df` of which first 4 integers match with the target date.
Result like this:

```rb
20010101 20010102 20010103
```

Comment: You can do `df %>% filter(str_detect(as.character(date), as.character(target_date)))` or `subset` `subset(df, grepl(as.character(target_date), date))`

Comment: Thank you for your comment @akrun, is there any way we can do it without converting it to character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `substr` to extract the first four character and then compare (`==`) with `target_date` to extract the subset of rows and pull the 'date' column

```
subset(df, substr(date, 1, 4) == target_date)$date
[1] 20010101 20010102 20010103
```

---

Or another option is to convert to `Date` class, extract the `year` and then `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  filter(year(ymd(date)) == target_date)
      date
1 20010101
2 20010102
3 20010103
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[floor(df$date/10000) == target_date,]
```